# Can the real field be made a vector space over the complex field?

Tags: vector-spaces

We all know that $ \mathbb{C} $ is naturally a vector space over $ \mathbb{R} $. However, is there some kind of (possibly weird) scalar multiplication law that would make $ \mathbb{R} $ a vector space over $ \mathbb{C} $ instead?

Comment: The best result that I've managed to produce is to show that $ \mathbb{R} $ is a vector space over $ \mathbb{Q} + i \mathbb{Q} $, the field of complex rationals.

Comment: Do you just want a vector space, or an algebra?

Comment: I only need a vector space. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. As an additive group, $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ (you can see this, for example, from the fact that they're both continuum-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$). Since the additive group $\mathbb{C}$ can be made into a complex vector space, so can the isomorphic group $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6):

Well, note that as abelian groups $(\mathbb C,+)$ and $(\mathbb R,+)$ are isomorphic. Since a vector space is merely an abelian group with scalar multiplication you can just pick a homomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ as additive groups, and use that to define a vector space.

In fact you can do the same trick with any finitely dimensional space over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Hi Asaf. I believe you meant 'pick an isomorphism between $ \mathbb{C} $ and $ \mathbb{R} $'. That is the only way one can transfer the vector space structure from $ \mathbb{C} $ to $ \mathbb{R} $.